# setTimeout callback fired in same tick of event loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible for the callback for a setTimeout call to fire in the same tick of the event loop that it was declared in?

for example we can call

```
setTimeout(function(){
   console.log('tic-tock');
}, 1);
```

it's possible that the event loop may be blocked for much more than 1ms, but I assume

```
setTimeout
```

callbacks are always pushed to the next tick of the JS event loop.

Answer (score 4):

Callback given to `setTimeout` cannot be executed in the same tick of the event loop.

Take a look at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Notes). It says:

"It's important to note that the function or code snippet cannot be executed until the thread that called setTimeout() has terminated."